# Google Indexing and Url

Tags: url, google-search

On my website, brand URLs like this

```
.../shopbybrands.aspx?auth=430&brand=AQUATALIA by MARVIN K
```

have no Hyphen or Underscore: **"AQUATALIA by MARVIN K"**. But when we  open the URL in a browser it looks like:

```
.../shopbybrands.aspx?auth=430&brand=AQUATALIA%20by%20MARVIN%20K
```

Automatically, **%20** appears in the URLs.  The issue is that if I search the first URL in Google, I will not get any results; but  if I search the second URLI do.

Also, in XML sitemap, URLs are included (e.g. the first URL) and I'm seeing in Google webmaster tool that only 35 URLs indexed out of 105. While I'm searching Google with %20 URLS, I'm getting index or results for the same but when I search the normal URL, like first, I don't.

So, please suggest what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: That's standard URL encoding:  Spaces are replaced by `%20`, just like anything that isn't alphanumeric.  It's supposed to appear that way to distinguish form from function.  I don't understand why you're searching an entire URL with query string.

Comment: Hello Gary, 

Thanks for the Quick Reply.

I got that question while I saw my indexing status in Google Webmaster Tool. In Google Webmaster, my Indexing Status is not improving from last 1 months. 

While I'm searching URLs with "%20" I am getting results in the Google but searching sitemap Urls (without %20) I'm not getting any results in the Google. 

It is confusing me too much, please help me what should i need to do???

Thanks